# How to get conversations list where last message belong to specific user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a tables `Users`, `Conversations`, `Messages`, all I need is to get list of conversation where last message belong to specific user only in Laravel Eloquent

`Users`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User 1 |
| 2 | User 2 |

`Conversation`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Conversation 1 |
| 2 | Conversation 2 |
| 3 | Conversation 3 |

`Messages`

| id | user_id | conversation_id | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | hi | 2022-23-12 19:33:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | hi | 2022-23-12 19:34:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | hello | 2022-23-12 19:35:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | hello | 2022-23-12 19:36:00 |

what I need, if I want to get conversation list of User (ID: 1) it needs to show me only Conversation 1(ID:1), because User 1 (ID: 1) wrote last message on this conversation and etc...

thanks for answer

I try a lot of thing like leftJoin and where condition and also try whereExists not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your relations are set up correctly, you can do:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->messages()
    ->latest()
    ->first()
    ->conversation;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#latest-oldest

Comment: Setting up relationships is the best way to tackle this! +1